# Dynamically named sets or other method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataset, set

First of all thank you for taking the time to look at my problem. Rather than simply describing the solution I have in mind for the problem I have to solve, I though it best to outline the problem also in order to enable alternative solution ideas to be suggested. It is more than likely that there is a better way to achieve this solution.

The problem I have:

I generate lists of names with associated scores ranks and other associated values, these lists are generated daily but have to change as the day progresses as a result of needing to remove some names. Currently these lists of names are produced on excel based sheets which contains the following data types in the following format;

```
(Unique List Title)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)

(Unique List Title)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
(Unique Name in list),(Rank),(Score),(Calculated Numeric Value)
```

For example;

```
Mrs Dodgsons class
Rosie,1,123.8,5
James,2,122.6,7
Chris,3,120.4,12

Dr Clements class
Hannah,1,126.9,2.56
Gill,2,124.54,6.89
Jack,3,122.04,15.62
Jamie,4,121.09,20.91
```

Now what I have is a separate list of users who need removing from the above excel generated lists (don't worry the final product of this little project is not to re-save a modified excel doc), this list is generated via a web scraper which is updated every two minutes. The method  I currently perceive as a potentially viable solution to this problem is to use a piece of code which saves each list in the CSV as a SET (if this is possible) then upon finding a Unique Name it would then delete them from the set/s in which they occur.

My questions to the python forum are;

1. is the methodology proposed viable with regards to producing multiple uniquely named SETs (up to 60 per day )
2. Is there a better method of achieving the same result ?

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated

Best regards AEA

Comment: Why are you all-caps'ing "set"? Are you referring to something other than Python's built-in set datatype?

Comment: No I am not, apologies for the confusion, I have edited the question as such. Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably be easier for you to use dictionaries rather than sets, as dictionaries, unlike sets, provide a natural way of associating items of data with each member of a collection.

Here's one approach, in which the data for each class is stored in a dictionary, each key of which is a student's name, and the values of which are lists with the scores, etc., of each student:

```
data = {
    "Mrs Dodgson": {
        "Rosie": [1,123.8,5],
        "James": [2,122.6,7],
        "Chris": [3,120.4,12]
    },
    "Dr Clement": {
        "Hannah": [1,126.9,2.56],
        "Gill": [2,124.54,6.89],
        "Jack": [3,122.04,15.62],
        "Jamie": [4,121.09,20.91]
    }
}

to_remove = ["Jamie", "Rosie"]

# Mrs. Dodgson's class data, initially.
print data["Mrs Dodgson"]

# Now remove the student data.
for cls_data in data.values():
    for student in to_remove:
        try:
            del cls_data[student]
        except KeyError:
            pass

print data["Mrs Dodgson"]
```